# HTML & CSS - Displaying images on Angles

Tags: html, css, image

I need to [display images on angles like shown below](http://www.datingjapan.co). Is CSS Transfer the way to do it?

[image]

```
/* Rotate div */
transform:rotate(7deg);
-ms-transform:rotate(7deg); /* Internet Explorer */
-moz-transform:rotate(7deg); /* Firefox */
-webkit-transform:rotate(7deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transform:rotate(7deg); /* Opera */
```

Would I just need to work out the correct degrees rotate for each image?
Sizing & Positioning are fine easy enough.

thx

Comment: Yes. That is all you need to do. Don't use a separate class for each image though. Do something like .container image:nth-of-type(1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I am totally agree with @Cody Guldner option. You just take all the images inside a list i.e

```
<ul>
  <li><img src="" alt="" /></li>
  <li><img src="" alt="" /></li>
  <li><img src="" alt="" /></li>
  <li><img src="" alt="" /></li>
  <li><img src="" alt="" /></li>
  <li><img src="" alt="" /></li>
</ul>
```

and for each image you can set your css that you have used, just add `nth-of-type(1)` and it will give you full control over the images.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for each image you need to give it a rotation. But you can also photoshop it with a degree with no background and save it as a png. That way you dont have to give it a rotation.